# jquery + php - Call Function From Another Javascript Wrapper

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, wrapper

How could I call function in different jQuery wrapper like this:

```
<?php
        if($trigger != ""){
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                    var delay = 5000;
                    setTimeout(rmv, delay); // call the function here
                });
            </script>           
            <?php                       
        }
        if($triggered != ""){
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                    function rmv(){ // function to be called
                        $(".adt_front_wrapper<?php echo $id; ?>").remove();
                    }
                });
            </script>           
            <?php                       
        }
?>
```

I am trying to call a function which should be separated from the caller like the `rmv` function in the example code above. How could it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to put that function into a higher (shared) scope. For this example, you could use the `window` object itself.

```
window.rmv = function() {
    $(".adt_front_wrapper<?php echo $id; ?>").remove();
};
```

In order to make that work, the declaration and definition of `rmv` needs to happen beforehand of course.